# Scikit Learn feature_selection giving different p-values

Tags: scikit-learn, feature-selection, p-value

I am getting two different sets of p-values when I use scikit learn's

```
predKbest= SelectKBest(sklearn.feature_selection.f_regression, k=i).fit(X_train, y_train)

predKbest.pvalues_
```

and

```
predKbest= SelectKBest(sklearn.feature_selection.chi2, k=i).fit(X_train, y_train)    
predKbest.pvalues_
```

on the same data X_train and y_train. Are they supposed to be different p-values?

Comment: Chi2 does a Chi2 test while f_regression is a fischer test. They are meant to be different.

Comment: @MohamedALANI I know that. My question is if pvalues for both these options are computed differently in the same function SelectKBest ?

Comment: I see, I didn't read your question well, sorry for that.
I believe they are computed the same way. Do you have the same number of variables after your two different features selection ?

Comment: @MohamedALANI, yes, they are exactly the same data. It might be that they have different hypothesis. However, the document related to these functions seem unclear to me so far.

Answer (score 2):

SelectKBest will select, in your case, the top i variables by importance, based on the test that you input : Fischer or Chi2.

F_regression is used for regression while chi2 is used for classification so it's quite strange that you use both of them with the same input variables. You should take a step back and study what you really are looking to do.
Everything is well explained here : http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html

f_regression p_value wil calculate the **linear** dependancy between each regressor and the target.

chi2 test "measures dependence between stochastic variables, so using this function “weeds out” the features that are the most likely to be independent of class and therefore irrelevant for classification." X must contains non-negative features such as booleans or frequencies.

The p_values that you print are here the results of the chi2 and f_regression that are "transformed" into p_values, so it's 100% normal that they are different.